# Transform class component to function component

Tags: reactjs

i Want to change this class component in function component:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DayPicker, { DateUtils } from "react-day-picker";
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDayClick = this.handleDayClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedDays: []
    };
  }

  handleDayClick(day, { selected }) {
    const { selectedDays } = this.state;
    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex((selectedDay) =>
        DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );
      selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      selectedDays.push(day);
    }
    this.setState({ selectedDays });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.state.selectedDays)}
        <DayPicker
          selectedDays={this.state.selectedDays}
          onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-chaum-0qss8?file=/src/App.js:0-944 
I did this:

```js
 const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState([])

    const handleDayClick = (day, {selected}) => {
        if (selected) {
            const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex(selectedDay =>
                DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
            );
            console.log('test',selectedDays);

            selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
        } else {
            // selectedDays.push(day)
            setSelectedDays([...selectedDays,day]);

        }
    }
    console.log(selectedDays);
    return (
        <div className="er">
            <DayPicker
                selectedDays={selectedDays}
                onDayClick={handleDayClick}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

The issue: When i select 1 date the date becomes active, but when i click again on it it does not change back into un-active state? What is the problem and how to solve?

Comment: How does the `day` look like? The problem is in `.splice` I'm nearly sure, but in order to understand how to fix it I'd like to see the day structure.

Comment: @Konstantin, what i want to achieve is next: when i will clik on a date it should be active but when i will click send time the date should change the state to normal. Could you help?

Comment: Can you please add how `day` looks then?

Comment: @Konstantin, what  do you mean? How looks when i click? I has a background that matrk the day as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is this working for you.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DayPicker, { DateUtils } from "react-day-picker";
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

export default App =()=> {
  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState([]);

  const handleDayClick=(day, { selected })=> {
    
    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex((selectedDay) =>
        DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );
      selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      selectedDays.push(day);
    }
    setSelectedDays( selectedDays );
  }

 
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.state.selectedDays)}
        <DayPicker
          selectedDays={selectedDays}
          onDayClick={handleDayClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  
}
```

Comment: does not work, when i click second time on the same date it should be unchecked but it does not happens

Comment: it is working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-chaum-0qss8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i need function component

Answer (score 0):

Have updated the answer, earlier i was actually mutating the state, which isnt the best practice.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DayPicker, { DateUtils } from "react-day-picker";
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

export default function Class1() {
  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState([]);
  function handleDayClick(day, { selected }) {
    const selectedDaysNew = [...selectedDays];
    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = selectedDaysNew.findIndex((selectedDay) =>
        DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );
      selectedDaysNew.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      selectedDaysNew.push(day);
    }
    setSelectedDays(selectedDaysNew);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(selectedDays)}
      <DayPicker selectedDays={selectedDays} onDayClick={handleDayClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is still mutating the state

Comment: Thanks, yes, my bad, have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's getting a bit hard to talk in the comments, so I'm gonna post an answer.

Does it change anything (it's a question) if you do it like this:

```
const handleDayClick=(day, { selected })=> {
const currentState = [...selectedDays];

    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = currentState.findIndex((selectedDay) =>
        DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );
      currentState.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      currentState.push(day);
    }
    setSelectedDays(currentState);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not mutate original state array, create a copy from state array first:

```
const handleDayClick = (day, {selected}) => {
  setSelectedDays(prevSelected => {
    const selectedDays = [...prevSelected]
    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex(selectedDay =>
          DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );
      console.log('test',selectedDays);

      selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
      return selectedDays
    } else {
      return [...selectedDays,day]
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never mutate state directly** you are doing some operation directly with muted state variable which may the cause for unappreciated bug.

please refer this links bellow [Why Not To Modify React State Directly](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/#:~:text=Mutating%20state%20directly%20can%20lead,its%20parent%20re-renders) and [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really) these concept apply the same for both class state or useState in components.

i just create a new array before proceeding and it's work fine. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-28-12-20-ov60y)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DayPicker, { DateUtils } from "react-day-picker";
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

export default () => {
  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState([]);
  const handleDayClick = (day, { selected }) => {
    const selectedDaysTemp = [...selectedDays]; // here is the change creating the new array 
    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = selectedDaysTemp.findIndex((selectedDay) =>
        DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );
      selectedDaysTemp.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      selectedDaysTemp.push(day);
    }
    setSelectedDays(selectedDaysTemp);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(selectedDays)}
      <DayPicker selectedDays={selectedDays} onDayClick={handleDayClick} />
    </div>
  );
};
```